# How to calculate the modulus in another way than using a while loop?

Tags: java

```
public static int compareAndReturn(int a, int b)
{
    while (a > b)
    {
        a -= b;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Is this homework? Think about how the result is computed and how the code may be shortened.

Comment: Are both `a` and `b` non-negative?

Comment: `modulo` read about this. You'll get a better idea.

Comment: This code does not compute the modulus, and the loop condition should be `while (a >= b)`.

Answer (score 5):

I believe your code snippet is just a manual way of computing the modulus, or remainder, when dividing `a` by `b`.  Your method could be rewritten as:

```
public static int compareAndReturn(int a, int b) {
    return a % b;
}
```

Comment: Ha, I didn't think about it this way. +1

Comment: This code does't work if I pass compareAndReturn(100, 5) but it will pass if compareAndReturn(100, 6)

Comment: @theSecretCoder Are you sure you copied the method correctly?  This is a common interview question, and the while condition usually is `while (a >= b)`

Comment: @theSecretCoder What do you mean by *"does't work if I pass compareAndReturn(100, 5)"*? If the method is intended to *"calculate the modulus"* (as you say in the title), then it should return `0`, and this method does, but your method doesn't, unless you change it to `while (a >= b)`, like Tim just said. If you expect `5`, which is what your code returns, then it is not *"calculating the modulus"*.

Comment: AS per the TIM code its works if while (a >= b) but it has while (a > b) so return a % b == 0 ? b : a % b; works correctly.

Answer (score 2):

You should eliminate the loop, since `a` can be much larger than `b`, which would result in many iterations of the loop.

```
public static int compareAndReturn(int a, int b) { 
    if (a <= b)
        return a;
    else if a % b == 0
        return b;
    else
        return a - (a/b) * b;
}
```

or

```
public static int compareAndReturn(int a, int b) { 
    return (a <= b) ? a : a % b == 0 ? b : a - (a/b) * b;
}
```

or (based on Tim's answer)

```
public static int compareAndReturn(int a, int b) { 
    return a % b == 0 ? b : a % b;
}
```

Comment: This code does't work if I pass compareAndReturn(100, 5) but it will pass if compareAndReturn(100, 6)

Comment: @theSecretCoder Yes, it requires an adjustment if a is divisible by b. I'll edit.